# Update existing entity framework with database (by adding new tables from db)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi i have an entity and i am gonna add two tables from database named as country and state.

There is a relation between these two tables based on CountryId.

I used the "Update Model from database ..." to add these two entity types.

[image]

I have manually written two classes for these two entity-types given as below:-

```
public partial class Country
{
    //[Key]    //[DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}

public partial class State
{
    public int StateID { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
}

public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
```

Controller to fetch coutries and states :-

```
public JsonResult GetCountries()
    {
        List<Country> allCountry = new List<Country>();
        using (SunilEntities dc = new SunilEntities())
        {
            allCountry = dc.Countries.OrderBy(a => a.CountryName).ToList();
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = allCountry, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }

public JsonResult GetStates(int countryID)
       {
           List<State> allState = new List<State>();
           using (SunilEntities dc = new SunilEntities())
           {
               allState = dc.States.Where(a => a.CountryID.Equals(countryID)).OrderBy(a => a.StateName).ToList();
           }
           return new JsonResult { Data = allState, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
       }
```

But I am getting an error "The entity type Country is not part of the model for the current context".

What should be the exact classes to be used to use these two tables in my controller?

Is there any way I can get automated classes after entity being updated with newer tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution change models as below:-

```
 public partial class Country
    {
        public Country()
        {
            this.States = new HashSet<State>();
        }

        public int CountryID { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; set; }
    }

  public partial class State
    {
        public int StateID { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CountryID { get; set; }

        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
        public virtual State State1 { get; set; }
        public virtual State State2 { get; set; }
    }
```

and change controller as given below:-

```
   public JsonResult GetCountries()
            {              
                using (SunilEntities dc = new SunilEntities())
                {
                    var ret = dc.Countries.Select(x => new { x.CountryID, x.CountryName }).ToList();
                    return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
                }
            }
            // Fetch State by Country ID
            public JsonResult GetStates(int countryID)
            {           
                using (SunilEntities dc = new SunilEntities())
                {                    
                    var ret = dc.States.Where(x => x.CountryID == countryID).Select(x => new { x.StateID, x.StateName }).ToList();
                    return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }              
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Under your yourmodel.edmx file there is yourmodel.tt and it generates relevant  classes, thus there is no need to write these classes. By using relevant namespace you can use them.

[image]

Comment: will it work for existing entity, when you add new tables in it?

Comment: Yes, you could try it